# Establish https connection to webcontainer hosted on Azure

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure, i am trying to connect to a service hosted on a web container(Tomcat 7) on my Azure VM. i have created a keystore there and also i have changed configuration of server.xml adding a connector with proper details.

when i am trying to access it form localhost(from Azure VM, taking remote access) https with self signed certificates works properly but when i am trying to connect from my local machine over the internet i am unable to connect.

PS. i am able to connect to same service hosted on the web container in Azure VM from my local machine, but once i change the connecter element in server.xml, i am unable to connect :(

Port 443 is not opened on the cloud/VM. i want to open the same, i have added an endpoint using Azure management portal but unable to proceed. need guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing a silly mistake of not checking if the port for communication is opened or not. opening the required port did the work for me. :)